# Plot mean and sd of dataset per x value using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that looks a little like this:

```
a <- data.frame(x=rep(c(1,2,3,5,7,10,15,20), 5),
                y=rnorm(40, sd=2) + rep(c(4,3.5,3,2.5,2,1.5,1,0.5), 5))
ggplot(a, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() +geom_smooth()
```

[image: graph output]

I want the same output as that plot, but instead of smooth curve, I just want to take line segments between the mean/sd values for each set of x values. The graph should look similar to the above graph, but jagged, instead of curved.

I tried this, but it fails, even though the x values aren't unique:

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() +stat_smooth(aes(group=x, y=y, x=x))
geom_smooth: Only one unique x value each group.Maybe you want aes(group = 1)?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try writing a summary function as suggested by Hadley Wickham on the website for `ggplot2`: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/stat_summary.html. Applying his suggestion to your code:

```
p <- qplot(x, y, data=a)

stat_sum_df <- function(fun, geom="crossbar", ...) { 
 stat_summary(fun.data=fun, colour="blue", geom=geom, width=0.2, ...) 
} 

p + stat_sum_df("mean_cl_normal", geom = "smooth")
```

This results in this graphic:

[image]

Comment: Nice. But I don't really understand why you're wrapping it in that function. Why not just use `p + stat_summary("mean_cl_normal", geom = "smooth", colour="blue", width=0.2)`? Also, what is the `width=0.2` for? Doesn't seem to make much difference to the output...

Comment: The function uses the summary functions from the `Hmisc` package. I thought the `width=0.2` would change the width of the line, but it doesn't seem to do anything as you say, so it apparently has no function!

Comment: `size` will change the width of the line.

Answer (score 8):

`?stat_summary` is what you should look at.

Here is an example

```
# functions to calculate the upper and lower CI bounds
uci <- function(y,.alpha){mean(y) + qnorm(abs(.alpha)/2) * sd(y)}
lci <- function(y,.alpha){mean(y) - qnorm(abs(.alpha)/2) * sd(y)}
ggplot(a, aes(x=x,y=y))  + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = 'line', colour = 'blue') + 
            stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = 'ribbon',fun.ymax = uci, fun.ymin = lci, .alpha = 0.05, alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use one of the built-in summary functions `mean_sdl`. The code is shown below

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
 stat_summary(fun.y = 'mean', colour = 'blue', geom = 'line')
 stat_summary(fun.data = 'mean_sdl', geom = 'ribbon', alpha = 0.2)
```

Comment: Yeah, saw that. `mean_sdl` includes a mean line though, so you don't need the second line.

Comment: @naught It does, but `geom='ribbon'` does not, so he needs the second line.

Answer (score 4):

Using ggplot2 0.9.3.1, the following did the trick for me:

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() +
 stat_summary(fun.data = 'mean_sdl', mult = 1, geom = 'smooth')
```

The 'mean_sdl' is an implementation of the Hmisc package's function 'smean.sdl' and the mult-variable gives how many standard deviations (above and below the mean) are displayed.

For detailed info on the original function:

```
library('Hmisc')
?smean.sdl
```