# Plotting in R, making vertical lines

Tags: r, plot

I have a problem, I have created something, SD+something, and something-SD, I want connect these points in vertical lines at each point any ideas?

```
#example code:
 hourvec;
 for (i in 1:length(hourvec)){plotUpper<- sd(hourvec) + hourvec}
 plotUpper;
 for (i in 1:length(hourvec)){plotLower<- hourvec - sd(hourvec)}
 plotLower;
 plot(RIL_table, type= "p", main="Variation in Longevity in DSPR RILs");
 points(plotUpper);
 points(plotLower);
```

Comment: This could help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033319/plot-mean-and-sd-of-dataset-per-x-value-using-ggplot2

Comment: Hi zx8754 this isnt excatly what I am looking for I am looking to make a plot with fly lines (x), hours (y) I want vertical lines on this plot with the SD+/- of hours.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking for. Is it something like [?abline](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/abline.html) or [?arrows](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/arrows.html)?

Comment: It would also help if you could add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) & what you want the output to look like.

Comment: Hi gung I dont have a plot like this, what I have is a dataframe that is has line name and hours, I created two vectors plotUpper and plotLower. when I plot them I have three sets of dots stacked. I want to connect these stacked dots with a vertical line, and repeat this for each set of stacked dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is a [candlestick chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candlestick_chart), try this:

```
#example data
set.seed(1); hourvec <- runif(20)
sd_hourvec <- sd(hourvec)

#get hourvec upper lower
plotUpper <- sd_hourvec + hourvec
plotLower <- hourvec - sd_hourvec

#plot
plot(hourvec, ylim = (c(-2, 2)))
for(x in seq_along(hourvec)) lines(c(x, x), c(plotUpper[ x ], plotLower[ x ]))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks zx8754 this is what I needed. Now my giant long code is ready.