# ggplot2: how to overlay 2 plots when using stat_summary

Tags: r, ggplot2

i am totally new in R so maybe the answer to the question is trivial but I couldn't find any solution after searching in the net for days.

I am using ggplot2 to create graphs containing the mean of my samples with the confidence interval in a ribbon (I can't post the pic but something like this: [S1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033319/plot-mean-and-sd-of-dataset-per-x-value-using-ggplot2)

I have a data frame (df) with time in the first column and the values of the variable measured in the other columns (each column is a replicate of the measurement).
I do the following:

```
mdf<-melt(df, id='time', variable_name="samples")
p <- ggplot(data=mdf, aes(x=time, y=value)) +
  geom_point(size=1,colour="red")


stat_sum_df <- function(fun, geom="crosbar",  ...) { 
  stat_summary(fun.data=fun, geom=geom, colour="red") 
} 

p + stat_sum_df("mean_cl_normal", geom = "smooth")
```

and I get the graph I have shown at the beginning.

My question is: if I have two different data frames, each one with a different variable, measured in the same sample at the same time, how I can plot the 2 graphs in the same plot?  Everything I have tried ends in doing the statistics in the both sets of data or just in one of them but not in both. Is it possible just to overlay the plots?

And a second small question: is it possible to change the colour of the ribbon?

Thanks!

Comment: Add a grouping variable to the data.frames, `rbind` them and pass the grouping variable to `group`, `colour` and/or `fill` in `aes`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you want you can link the image and someone could edit your question to add the image. This questions seems to me that are explained in the `ggplot2` help page, the first question I think [this](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/gg-add.html) could be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
a <- data.frame(x=rep(c(1,2,3,5,7,10,15,20), 5),
                y=rnorm(40, sd=2) + rep(c(4,3.5,3,2.5,2,1.5,1,0.5), 5),
                g = rep(c('a', 'b'), each = 20))

ggplot(a, aes(x=x,y=y, group = g, colour = g)) + 
 geom_point(aes(colour = g)) +
 geom_smooth(aes(fill = g))
```

[image]

I'd suggest you reading the basics of ggplot. Check `?ggplot2` for help on ggplot but also available help topics [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/index.html) and particularly how [group aesthetic](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/aes_group_order.html) may be manipulated.
You'll find useful the [discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ggplot2) at Google groups and maybe join it. Also, QuickR have a lot of examples on [ggplot graphs](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/ggplot2.html) and, obviously, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ggplot2) at Stackoverflow.